# Do I need to use LogStash to process ElasticSearch data for visualization in a Kibana dashboard?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

In a current application, we retain all requests in a SQL Server database table.  Since we will be moving to ElasticSearch, can I simply just serialize the data entry (creating the JSON object representation) and throwing that into an ElasticSearch type to be used for a Kibana dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Logstash to ingest the data into Elasticsearch. Logstash
is simply a tool used to read data from a location, transform it, and then write
it to an output.

You can always write something yourself, or use a different tool to get the data
from your SQL database into Elasticsearch. Once in Elasticsearch, Assuming it is
inserted in a proper manner, Kibana will be able to read it.